# Detect Private Browsing - Safari Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am trying to detect if a user is viewing a website in a private browser. I have the below code/fiddle that works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. Can anyone see what the issue is for Safari? Thank you in advance.

```
new Promise(resolve => {
let db,
on = () => alert('yes'),
off = () => alert('no'),
tryls = () => {
    try {
        localStorage.length ? off() : (localStorage.x = 1, localStorage.removeItem("x"), off())
    } catch (e) {
        on()
    }
}

// Blink
window.webkitRequestFileSystem ? 
    webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1, off, on)

// FF
: "MozAppearance" in document.documentElement.style ? 
    (db = indexedDB.open("test"), db.onerror = on, db.onsuccess = off)

// Safari
: /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) ?
    tryls()

// IE10+ & edge
: !window.indexedDB && (window.PointerEvent || window.MSPointerEvent) ? 
    on()

// Rest
: off()
 }).then(enabled => {
document.body.innerHTML = enabled
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ndyL5mxf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for anyone that may come across. Safari in private mode doesn't handle local storage so the below codes tests to see if there is local storage and if it doesn't, do something. Worked for my issue.

```
var storageTestKey = 'test';
var storage = window.sessionStorage;
try {
     storage.setItem(storageTestKey, 'test');
     storage.removeItem(storageTestKey);
    } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === DOMException.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR && storage.length === 0) {
        console.log('private widow')
    } else {
        console.log('not private')
    }
}
```